# Parallel network downloading in a for-loop in C++14

Tags: c++, networking, parallel-processing, c++14

I have a list of links I want to download data from in parallel.

What is the best way of launching a number of downloading jobs in parallel and fetching the results?

My sequential loop looks something like this:

```
vector<string> download_results;

for (string link : links) {
   string data = download_data(link);
   download_results.push_back(data);
}
```

How can I launch `download_data(link)` in parallel *while keeping the arrangement of data* in `download_results` the same as in the sequential loop above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::future<std::string>> downloads;

for (string link : links) {
  auto data = std::async( std::launch::async, [link]{return download_data(link);} )
  downloads.push_back(std::move(data));
}
std::vector<std::string> download_results;
for( auto&& dl:downloads ){
  download_results.push_back(f.get());
}
```

---

This can be improved by limiting the number of connections and using `reserve`.  For example, with a thread pool, or a queue of futures that you start poping off when you hit the limit.  Thread pool is best in my opinion as it queues up a new download when any of the old ones finish, while the queue could stall on an early large download.

You could in theory write the "only 10 downloads active" code bespoke, but that is mixing business logic with resource management.

I have posted `threaded_queue` and `thread_pool` on SO in the past; google will find them.

Comment: What a beautiful answer, I wish I could +1 multiple times.

Comment: Is `f` supposed to be `dl` in the last loop?

Comment: @yari if this solves your problem, press the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Resize `download_results` to `links.size()` and then assign the data accordingly:

You can launch threads in the loop calling lambdas capturing link indices by value, `download_results` and `links` by reference, or do this with OpenMP.

In the first case however, I don't think you should be always creating `links.size()` number of threads.

Note that in C++17, you can simply call `std::transform` with a parallel execution policy.

Comment: In c++17 `std::transform` for example: `transform(par, begin(links), end(links), back_inserter(download_results), [](auto link) { return download_data(link); }`

Comment: Right, it is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found, when I was having a problem was to use **OpenMP** [loop parallelism](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-loop.html). It is simple and effective.

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
for (i=0; i<N; i++) 
{
  // do something with i
}
```

But in your case as you are using `download_results.push_back(data);` so for ordered loop use this,

```
#pragma omp parallel for ordered
```

Your code should look like this.

```
vector<string> download_results;

#pragma omp parallel for ordered
for (string link : links) 
{
   string data = download_data(link);

#pragma omp ordered
   download_results.push_back(data);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this with the C++14 standard library?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45729142/2949645) suggests the best approach currently being used in C++14, I suggested of using [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) which is a ready-made type of API for parallel processing.